# postgresql port closed for remote access

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, port, connection

I'm trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database in an Ubuntu Server, which I have root access, but somehow I can't open port 5432 for remote access, just local. This is what happens when I use "nmap" command on the server (XXX.XXX.X.XX represents server's IP):

```
nmap -p 5432 localhost
PORT      STATE  SERVICE 
5432/tcp  open   postgresql


nmap -p 5432 XXX.XXX.X.XX
PORT      STATE  SERVICE 
5432/tcp  closed postgresql
```

I have already edited the files 'pg_hba.conf' and 'postgresql.conf' but it didn't work.

**The changes:**

pg_hba.conf file:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             all            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             all            md5
```

postgresql.conf file:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

And when i try to connect with pgAdmin III, this is what it shows me:

> **Server doesn't listen**
>
> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is
>   the server running on host "XXX.XXX.X.XX" and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

I have tried to open the port using "ufw" command but it didin't work as well.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: did you restart the postgresql service after modifying those settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your firewall is not blocking traffic.

Append the following rules to your iptables (change `X.X.X.X` to your server IP address):

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d X.X.X.X  --dport 5432 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s X.X.X.X --sport 5432 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

If it works, save the iptables and restart it:

```
# apt-get install iptables-persistent
# /etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

If you have an external firewall on your network, you should allow the connection there as well.

**Security note:** opening your PostgreSQL port to public might be a security concern. You should consider limiting the incoming traffic to specific IP address/range by changing the `-s 0/0` parameter in the first iptables command to `-s X.X.X.X/X`